# Can't drag folder from one project to another in xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am trying to use facebook connect and you sare supposed to be able to drag and drop folders but it doesn't work in XCode 4! any ideas?

Update 1/8/2017:  This is still true in Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 18):

Previously: 
drag folder from project A to project B.
Now:
1. in project A, right click - show in finder
2. finder - go up a level
3. drag the folder into project B
4. delete unnecessary files inside the newly added folder

---

Good job, Apple.

PS: And it doesn't work for groups, as @zeeple mentioned in comments.

Comment: Boo on Apple.  When you have a tremendous number of assets sorted meticulously into groups in the project it is worse than useless to "show in Finder..." because in Finder the folder structure you have created in the project is not duplicated.  BTW, this seems to still be true 5 years later in Xcode 8.  Boo on Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Dragging resources between projects in XCode is generally a bad idea in my opinion, even if it is supported.  When you drag and drop something in XCode, it doesn't actually create a new copy of that thing, it just adds a new reference to its old location.

This can be very bad, because now changing the resource in one project will make the same changes appear in the other.  The vast majority of the time this *is not* what you want.  SCM further complicates things, because if you add a resource to `Project B` by dragging from `Project A` and then check in the changes and then some other developer checks out just `Project B`, they will be missing the resources that you "added" to `Project B`.

So instead of dragging and dropping in XCode, I suggest using the Finder or the command line to explicitly copy your resources into the destination project's source tree.  Then in XCode just add the copied files to the project the same way you normally would.

Comment: What you say is true, but it fails to recognize shared files. I've created specific "Library" folders of code that I reuse from app to app. So, as you should know, copying that would require parallel updates. As well, people can create a "Group" in a project that holds files from various locations. So, the finder approach would be very laborious in that instance.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that it's the official way of adding source code from some popular library (such as Google Data). I sincerely hope Apple won't do those kind of big changes to their IDE every 3 years.

Comment: @aroth I get what you are saying but that isn't completely true -- you used to be able to check "Copy files" which would copy the entire folder of source code rather than just creating a pointer to that folder.

Comment: Usability fail for unsupported drag folder across project, xCode should be asking about things that copying instead unsupport that